# I'm trying to use a LayoutInflator Factory with MvvmCross, but it isn't working

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to follow the example here, but use this with MvvmCross:

http://motzcod.es/post/62100709977/super-roboto-fonts-custom-layoutinflater-ifactory-in

Which shows how to use the Roboto font family (and other fonts) in older versions of Android OS in Xamarin apps.

My guess is that the extension method BindingInflate isn't using the LayoutInflator.Factory I'm setting. How do you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> **"** My guess is that the extension method BindingInflate isn't using the LayoutInflator.Factory I'm setting.
>   **How do you fix this? "**

A good question that apparently has gone unanswered for the last 1.5 years!

Here is the solution...

1. In your mark-up, add a Typeface binding, like this:

   `<TextView
           android:id="@+id/welcome_title"
           style="@style/WelcomeTitle"
           local:MvxBind="Text myBoundText; Typeface StringToFont('Roboto-Thin')" />`
2. Include your MvvmCross Typeface converter:

   ```
   public class StringToFontConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, Typeface>
   {
       private static readonly Dictionary<string, Typeface> Cache = new Dictionary<string, Typeface> ( );

       protected override Typeface Convert ( string fontName, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
       {
           try
           {
               if ( ! fontName.StartsWith ( @"Fonts/" ) ) fontName = @"Fonts/" + fontName;
               if ( ! fontName.EndsWith ( ".ttf" ) ) fontName += ".ttf";

               if ( ! Cache.ContainsKey ( fontName ) ) {
               Cache[fontName] = Typeface.CreateFromAsset ( Application.Context.Assets, fontName );
               }

               return Cache[fontName];
           }
           catch ( Exception e )
           {
               Android.Util.Log.Error ( "AndroidFont", e.ToString ( ) );
               return Typeface.Default;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**NOTE:** I do not particularly like this solution, because it does not inject a default font, as would be done with a Xamarin component like "Calligraphy".

Unfortunately I have not been able to find an MvvmCross "android view inflation extensibility" feature today, but am looking into ways such a feature could be introduced without having to branch the MvvmCross source code.

Answer (score 0):

MvvmCross itself uses a custom `LayoutInflator.Factory` and uses custom attributes for binding. Because of this, it's not currently easy (I can't think of an easy way) to combine the technique in that article as is with MvvmCross.

However:

- you can easily use the earlier version of that technique - http://motzcod.es/post/61775933477/beautiful-android-compat-roboto-fonts-in
- I'll add "android view inflation extensibility" to the project backlog - so it should be possible in the near future

Comment: The issue for this is: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/491 and this is fixed in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/1022 in case anyone find this later.